# I need feedback on how to open a ``file.txt`` on Python

Tags: python

I am a student in year 11 and I can't seem to make a code that opens a `txt` file in Python, I tried saving them in the same place and it still didn't work any help please?

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote to open the file?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) then come back if you have any questions.

Comment: Help with what? There's nothing more specific for us to help with other than writing it for you.

Comment: import random
with open('10 five-letter words.txt') as f: thats the code i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a file in Python you use [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).
In good Python usage you use `open()` with `with` so that it automaticly closes the file for you after you're done with the file.

So in example form:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    #The file is now open and you can iterate over the lines
    for line in file:
        print line
```

In your comment you're forgetting the `mode` part, which specifies what you want to do with your file, in this example `r` stands for `read` which is the default if you omit it.
`w` stands for `write` and `r+` for `reading and writing`. Read this all in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: `'r'` is implied if it’s missing

Comment: ill send most of it because i cant send that much

Comment: import random
with open('10 five-letter words.txt') as f:
    words = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],9)
    grid = [words[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]
    for x,y,z in grid:
        print(x,y,z)
        
input("")
with open ('10 five-letter words.txt') as f:
    the10=random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],10)
print('the orignal grid of words are: ',the10)
print('these are 10 words')

Comment: @Marshall.Oofa That’s unreadable, edit your question instead.

Comment: @Mathias, yes I mention that further on, but for example sake it is good to mention the `mode`.

Comment: @Ruben sorry, didn't saw that part

Comment: @Marshall.Oofa This is getting rather vague, did you figure it out? Else edit your question, and I'll edit my answer to your needs.